# Error en referencia cruzada con herencia en C++

Tags: c++, lista, codeblocks

Tengo una clase **Nodo**, **Lista** y **Venta**, desde la clase **Lista** llamo a la Clase **Nodo** la cual a su vez llama a la clase **Venta** pero también la clase **Venta** llama a la clase **Lista** lo cual deja un problema de referencia cruzada. Como solución hice esto:

```
class Lista;
```

Antes de declarar la clase **Venta**

Les dejare el codigo.

Nodo.h

```
#ifndef NODO_H_INCLUDED
#define NODO_H_INCLUDED
#include "Objeto.h"
#include "Venta.h"
#include "Cliente.h"
#include "Producto.h"

class Nodo {
    private:
        Nodo *Siguiente;
        Objeto *elemento;
    public:
        Nodo(Objeto *v, Nodo *sig=NULL) {
            this->elemento = v;
            this->Siguiente = sig;
        }
        Objeto *getElemento() {
            return this->elemento;
        }
        friend class Lista;
};

#endif // NODO_H_INCLUDED
```

Lista.h

```
#ifndef LISTA_H_INCLUDED
#define LISTA_H_INCLUDED
#include "Nodo.h"

class Lista {
    private:
        Nodo *Primero;
        Nodo *Ultimo;
    public:
        Lista() {
            this->Primero = NULL;
            this->Ultimo = NULL;
        }
        bool ListaVacia() {
            return (this->Primero == NULL);
        }
        bool Insertar(Objeto *v) {
            Nodo *nuevo = new Nodo(v);
            if (this->ListaVacia()) {
                this->Primero = nuevo;
            } else {
                this->Ultimo->Siguiente = nuevo;
            }
            this->Ultimo = nuevo;
            return true;
        }
       Nodo *Buscar(int v) {
            Nodo *tmp = this->Primero;
            Nodo *retorno = NULL;
            bool encontrado = false;
            while(tmp && !encontrado) {
                switch(tmp->elemento->getTipoObjeto()) {
                    case 1:
                        if(v == static_cast<Cliente*>(tmp->elemento)->getIdCliente()) {
                            encontrado = true;
                            retorno = tmp;
                        } else {
                            tmp = tmp->Siguiente;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if(v == static_cast<Producto*>(tmp->elemento)->getIdProducto()) {
                            encontrado = true;
                            retorno = tmp;
                        } else {
                            tmp = tmp->Siguiente;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return retorno;
        }
        void Mostrar(int t) {
            Nodo *tmp = this->Primero;
            Cliente *c;
            Producto *p;
            Venta *v;
            switch(t) {
                case 1:
                    cout << "ID\t\tNombres\t\tApellidos\n";
                    while(tmp) {
                        c = static_cast<Cliente*>(tmp->elemento);
                        cout << c->getIdCliente() << "\t\t" << c->getNombres() << "\t\t" << c->getApellidos() << "\n";
                        tmp = tmp->Siguiente;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "ID\t\tDescripcion\t\tUnidad de medida\t\tPrecio\n";
                    while(tmp) {
                        p = static_cast<Producto*>(tmp->elemento);
                        cout << p->getIdProducto() << "\t\t" << p->getDescripcion() << "\t\t\t" << p->getUnidadMedida().getUnidadMed() << "\t\t\t\t$" << p->getPrecioUnitario() << "\n";
                        tmp = tmp->Siguiente;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << "No\t\tNombre\t\t\tFecha\t\tCantidad\n";
                    while(tmp) {

                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        int Contar() {
            int cont = 0;
            Nodo *tmp = this->Primero;
            while(tmp) {
                cont++;
                tmp = tmp->Siguiente;
            }
            return cont;
        }
};

#endif // LISTA_H_INCLUDED
```

Venta.h

```
#ifndef VENTA_H_INCLUDED
#define VENTA_H_INCLUDED
#include "Objeto.h"
#include "Cliente.h"
#include "Producto.h"
#include "Lista.h"

class Lista;

class Venta : public Objeto {
    private:
        int noFactura;
        string fechaVenta;
        Cliente cliente;
        Lista *ProductosVendidos;
    public:
        Venta() {
            this->noFactura = 0;
            this->fechaVenta = "";
            this->cliente = Cliente();
            this->ProductosVendidos = Lista();
        }
        Venta(int i, string f, Cliente c) {
            this->noFactura = i;
            this->fechaVenta = f;
            this->cliente = c;
            this->ProductosVendidos = Lista();
        }
        void setNumeroFactura(int n) {
            this->noFactura = n;
        }
        int getNumeroFactura() {
            return this->noFactura;
        }
        void setFecha(string f) {
            this->fechaVenta = f;
        }
        string getFecha() {
            return this->fechaVenta;
        }
        void setCliente(Cliente c) {
            this->cliente = c;
        }
        Cliente getCliente() {
            return this->cliente;
        }
        void agregarProducto(Producto *p) {
            this->ProductosVendidos.Insertar(p);
        }
        Lista getListaProductos() {
            return this->ProductosVendidos;
        }
        int getNumeroProductos() {
            return this->ProductosVendidos.Contar();
        }
        virtual int getTipoObjeto() {
            return 3;
        }
};

#endif // VENTA_H_INCLUDED
```

El error "invalid used of incomplete type 'class Lista'" lo obtengo en *Venta.h* en la linea 21, especificamente donde dice:

```
this->ProductosVendidos = Lista();
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero es eliminar las referencias cruzadas que no se necesitan.

Si una clase únicamente necesita almacenar un puntero y no hace absolutamente nada con el, entonces con un *declaration forward* te sobra:

```
#ifndef NODO_H_INCLUDED
#define NODO_H_INCLUDED
// No hacen falta
// #include "Objeto.h"
// #include "Venta.h"
// #include "Cliente.h"
// #include "Producto.h"

class Objeto; // declaration forward

class Nodo {
    private:
        Nodo *Siguiente;
        Objeto *elemento;
    public:
        Nodo(Objeto *v, Nodo *sig=NULL) {
            this->elemento = v;
            this->Siguiente = sig;
        }
        Objeto *getElemento() {
            return this->elemento;
        }
        friend class Lista;
};

#endif // NODO_H_INCLUDED
```

A continuación mueves las implmementaciones a archivos .cpp. En C++ separar la declaración de la implementación es importantísimo ya que así se evitan muchísimos problemas:

- Los archivos de implementación no suelen ser usados en los `#include`, lo que evita dependencias cruzadas
- El contenido de las cabeceras se incluye en todos los fuentes que las incluyan. Cada vez que se modifica una cabecera hay que recompilar todos los archivos dependientes
- Efecto colateral del caso anterior: Si un archivo no se recompila se pueden producir desalineamientos (un archivo tiene una implementación y otro otra) y eso provoca errores rarísimos en tiempo de ejecución

**Nodo.h**

```
#ifndef NODO_H_INCLUDED
#define NODO_H_INCLUDED

class Objeto;

class Nodo {
        Nodo *Siguiente;
        Objeto *elemento;
    public:
        Nodo(Objeto *v, Nodo *sig=nullptr);
        Objeto *getElemento() const;

        friend class Lista;
};

#endif // NODO_H_INCLUDED
```

**Nodo.cpp**

```
Nodo::Nodo(Objeto *v, Nodo *sig=NULL)
{
  this->elemento = v;
  this->Siguiente = sig;
}

Objeto * Nodo::getElemento() const
{
  return this->elemento;
}
```

Ah si, se me olvidaba... procura no pasarle un objeto a un puntero:

```
this->ProductosVendidos = Lista();
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^
//    puntero             objeto
```

En su lugar usa `new`, si es lo que realmente necesitas:

```
this->ProductosVendidos = new Lista;
```